# Behaviour difference between HashSet and LinkedHashSet for Knights Path solution

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator, hashset, linkedhashset

I'm seeing a strange behaviour in a coding puzzle I was working on 'Knights Path'. I generate the set of possible moves and store these in a HashSet (the Move class simply has an x,y co-ordinates and a standard hashcode and equals). When I use a HashSet in the generateMoves() method the program doesn't find a solution whereas when I change to the LinkedHashSet it does.

```
public static Collection<Move> generateMoves(int startX, int startY){
    Set<Move> moves = new HashSet<Move>(); <-- doesn't work

public static Collection<Move> generateMoves(int startX, int startY){
    Set<Move> moves = new LinkedHashSet<Move>(); <-- works
```

I know that HashSet doesn't provide any guarantees on the ordering of the iterator elements but the ordering of the moves should not matter in terms of the eventual finding of a solution using backtracking method (some ordering of moves would be more optimal than others but with this brute force approach eventually all paths should be considered).

Clearly there is something funky going on with the iterator of the Collection from HashSet but I have conducted multiple tests to compare the output of the generateMoves for every board position using a LinkedHashSet and a HashSet and they are the same.

Full code below, any pointers greatly appreciated as I'm very curious to understand what may be going on here!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class KnightTour {

    private static int countSteps = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] board = new int[8][8];
        board[0][0] = 1;
        solveTour(board,0,0,1);
    }

    public static class Move{
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "["+ x + "," + y + "]";
        }
        int x;
        int y;
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + x;
            result = prime * result + y;
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Move other = (Move) obj;
            if (x != other.x)
                return false;
            if (y != other.y)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static void printBoard(int[][] board){
        System.out.println("---------");
        for(int i=0;i <8;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                if(board[i][j] != 0){
                    System.out.print('x');
                }else{
                    System.out.print('0');
                }

            }
            System.out.println('\r');
        }
        System.out.println("---------");
    }

    public static boolean solveTour(int[][] sol, int x, int y, int movei){
        countSteps++;
        if(countSteps%100000 == 0){
            System.out.println("Count:"+countSteps);
        }

        Collection<Move> moves = generateMoves(x,y);

        if(movei == 64){
            printBoard(sol);
            return true;
        }

        for(Move tryMove : moves){
            int next_x = tryMove.x;
            int next_y = tryMove.y;

            if(isValidMove(sol, next_x,next_y)){
                sol[next_x][next_y] = movei;
                if(solveTour(sol, next_x, next_y, movei+1)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    sol[next_x][next_y] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isValidMove(int[][] board, int destX, int destY){
        if(destX < 0 || destX > 7 || destY < 0 || destY > 7){
            return false;//Off the board!
        }

        return board[destX][destY] == 0;
    }

    public static Collection<Move> generateMoves(int startX, int startY){
        Set<Move> moves = new HashSet<Move>();//Doesn't terminate
//      Set<Move> moves = new LinkedHashSet<Move>();//Works with Linked

        for(int i=-2; i<=2; i++){
            for(int j=-2; j<=2; j++){
                if(Math.abs(i) == Math.abs(j) || i == 0 || j==0 ){
                    //no op
                }else{
                    Move m = new Move();
                    m.x = startX + i;
                    m.y = startY + j;
                    moves.add(m);
                }
            }
        }

        return moves;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you might be seeing is a side effect of `LinkedHashMap` iteration, which guarantees to iterate in the order of insert. `HashSet` does not have this same guarantee and can return the results in any order.

I think that the ordering of moves is probably important to your algorithm and perhaps an accidental heuristic you are applying by traversing in that order. The random ordering of moves may increase the complexity and introduce many new and suboptimal routes to explore recursively.

The `HashSet` solution might complete, it might be interesting to try with a small board and see if you get a result from that.